# DataFrame isn't dropping duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've seen other people pose this question, but I have been through the solutions and nothing is working so far.

My DataFrame isn't dropping duplicates. I don't know how to fix it.

```
combined_input_dat = pd.concat([input_dat, subcatch_dat_big], axis=1)
combined_dat = pd.concat([combined_input_dat, output_nolid_dat], axis=1)
date_first = date(2010,1,1)
date_last = date(2020,12,31)
date_delta = date_last-date_first
row_names_date = [(date_first + timedelta(days=i)).strftime('%m/%d/%Y') for i in range(date_delta.days + 1) ]
n_subcatchments = 140
row_names_date_long = np.repeat(row_names_date, n_subcatchments)
combined_input_dat['date']= row_names_date_long
combined_input_dat.drop_duplicates(keep=False,inplace=True)
```

I'm able to drop the duplicates before this code, but not after. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide dummy dataset.

Comment: Why would there be a date time index? You assign your dates and times that you generate to the column `date`.